# Accessing type="file" input from POST method on server side

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, post

Having some difficulty understanding how to access type="file" input on the server side. Below is the code I'm using. I use AJAX because I want my web app to not require refreshing, and am using a slightly roundabout way of submitting my form so I can have a better UI.

My HTML:

```
<form id="updateProfileImageForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="updateProfileImageContainer">
              <img src="images/profile/generic.png" class="updateProfileImage">
              <div class="updateProfileImageOverlay" onclick="changeImageToUpload()">
                <div class="updateProfileImageOverlayText">Upload new image</div>
              </div>
              <input type="file" id="imageToUpload" name="image" style="display: none;" onChange="$(this).closest('form').trigger('submit');"></input>
            </div>
          </form>
```

My JS:

```
function changeImageToUpload() {
  $('#imageToUpload').trigger('click');
}    

$('#updateProfileImageForm').submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var form_data = new FormData(this);

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/changeProfile',
        data: form_data,
        processData: false,
        success: function(response) {
          if(response.message != null) {
            alert(response.message);
          } else {
            // Change profile image displayed
            $('.updateProfileImage').attr("src", response.newProfileImage);
            alert('Profile picture successfully updated! Refresh your browser to update your window!');
          }
        }
      })
    });
```

My Server PHP:

```
if (isset($_FILES['image'])) {
      $image = $_FILES['image'];
  }
```

Var_dump on $_FILES shows an empty array, while var_dump on $_POST shows a lot of information (which I'm assuming is my data file). However, accessing the 'image' property on either $_POST or $_FILES (through either $_POST['image'] or $_FILES['image']) gives me either "undefined index" or "undefined variable".

Would you guys be so kind as to educate me on:

1. What's the difference between $_POST and $_FILES?
2. How should I be accessing the file in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: Both `$_POST` and `$_FILES` are superglobal variables that stores different informations. You can access files informations only using `$_FILES`. There is also `$_REQUEST` which returns both post and files informations. Ok. So let's recapitulate, `$_POST` returns all data from a form excluding inputs of type files, and `$_FILES` does the opposite.

Comment: The following shouldn't be the cause of the problem but lets rule out possibilities. Remove the style='display:none' from the control and see if it works. If it does then use the style='position:absolute; left:-999px;'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a necessary config option in your ajax request, you need to set contentType to false

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/changeProfile',
    data: form_data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function(response) {
      if(response.message != null) {
        alert(response.message);
      } else {
        // Change profile image displayed
        $('.updateProfileImage').attr("src", response.newProfileImage);
        alert('Profile picture successfully updated! Refresh your browser to update your window!');
      }
    }
  })
```

jQuery.ajax sets the content type by default to application/x-www-form-urlencoded which is incorrect for your FormData object, if you set it to false it will be set correctly by the underlying XMLHTTTPRequest object.

Answer (score -1):

Idea behind it.
Instead of using file as post to PHP, simply convert image to base64 and receive that string using ajax in php.

[Refer to this URL](https://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/)

Comment: That is an ugly way to deal with file uploads. What would you do if the type of the file is not an image?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: As you're uploading only image so there you should use validation to detect an image is valid or not. In other cases it will not helpful.

Comment: Please [edit] the externally hosted code into the post; doing so will make sure it remains useful even if the link breaks. My script [is not allowed to do this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/344512/4751173) because of potential licensing problems.